# How can I upload an Image selected from the Gallery onto a PHP server in android?

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, image-uploading, android-image

So I can successfully let the user select an image from the gallery without any problems (I've checked it by setting the selected Image onto an ImageView). I've made an AsyncTask class which does the uploading. I pass the Image as a base64 encoded String with the help of this function (which I think works fine):

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

I also pass the session username as a parameter (for the naming of the Image that will be uploaded).

Here's the AsyncTask Activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundPhotoUpload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String encodedImage;
    Context context;
    String usernameSignUp;

    BackgroundPhotoUpload(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        usernameSignUp = params[0];
        encodedImage = params[1];
        try {
            String loginUrl = "xxx";
            URL url = new URL(loginUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("encodedImage", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(encodedImage, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(usernameSignUp, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String datarecieved = "";
            while ((datarecieved = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += datarecieved;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Starting Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here's how I am calling the AsyncTask Class from the main class:

```
BackgroundPhotoUpload backgroundWorker = new BackgroundPhotoUpload(this);
backgroundWorker.execute(usernameSignUp, encodedString);
```

On deploying the app, I only see the first Toast Message:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Starting Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The app crashes before giving the second Toast Message:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The PHP script hosted on the server worked perfectly fine when I manually gave the inputs. So I think it's a problem with the AsyncTask Class.

But here's the PHP script anyways:

```
<?php 
    require 'init.php';
    if(isset($_GET["encodedImage"]) && isset($_GET["username"])) {
        $imageEncoded = $_GET["encodedImage"];
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $imageDecoded = base64_decode($imageEncoded);
        $path = "images/profilePic_".$username.".jpg";
        file_put_contents($path,$imageDecoded);
        echo "Successfully updated!";
    }
    else {
            echo "An error occurred.";
    }

?>
```

It's surprising why only Uploading Image part crashes the app. I've made a login and a signUp page with the same AsyncTask Activity (differences being the targetURL and the headers obviously) that work completely fine.

Any solutions to this issue?

Comment: And yeah, I've also given INTERNET permission in the Manifest file.

Comment: Why don't you try ANDROID NETWORK LIBRARY? Like Volley or okHTTP etc..